# How can I insert another model of antenna into the .NED of a traffic simulation?

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I would like to introduce a Directional Antenna Model where I can change the gains of them so I can compare the results with the Default Omnidirectional Antenna (Isotropic Antenna) of the program.

I am using Veins 5.0, SUMO 0.19 and Omnet++ within the Github Carlogicapi  found in https://github.com/burtonwilliamt/carlogicapi/blob/master/tutorials/VeinsTutorial/README.md

How can I do so? 
Should I create a new model and then insert it? if so where should I insert it? directly in the .ini ?
how can I make omnet++ use the model I give him?

Here I have some useful links about the antenna's models I found in inet.omnetpp.org (https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/showcases/wireless/directionalantennas/doc/)

would you give me a hand please?
[inet.omnetpp](https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/showcases/wireless/directionalantennas/doc/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Veins 5.0 tutorial simulation sets the antenna pattern to use in line 87 of its `omnetpp.ini` https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5.0/examples/veins/omnetpp.ini#L87. It also comes with a variety of other (more or less directional) antenna patterns (namely `panorama` and `patch`), which are stored in other fragments of the same xml file: https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5.0/examples/veins/antenna.xml

Comment: Well I actually do not have it directly in my omnetpp.ini, I have it in my BasePhyLayer, but I guess wherever I change it, i will affect the simulation right?

Which one between the "patch" and "panorama" is "more" directional?

If I really wanted to get a Parabolic Antenna, would that be possible? what should I do?

Thank you very much Mister Sommer. You are a legend.:)

Comment: Depends on which direction you prefer. For a quick overview of the mentioned patterns, see the paper available at https://www.cms-labs.org/bib/eckhoff2016impact/ (Figure 1). An overview of how to define custom patterns is available at https://veins.car2x.org/documentation/modules/ (essentially: supply a list of arbitrary gain values, sampled equidistantly around 360 degrees - could be as coarse as 4 samples i.e. every 90 degrees or as fine as 360 samples i.e. one sample every degree)